# Crystal Reports Runtime files to include in our setup.exe

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, reporting

Given that the runtime/redistributable for Crystal Reports for Visual Studion 2010 is 72 Mb, we are looking for an alternative to including this "msi" in our setup.exe and shipping to our customers.

Has anyone discovered an alternative to shipping this msi, by including only those files and custom actions needed by their app - we are deploying a C# thick client app [not a web based app] therefore do not need the webserver components that are included in the msi.

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

It's a waste of time to figure out what is and what is not needed with the Crystal runtimes. The current Crystal runtime installer is great, and most everything in the installer is needed. What might not be needed is minor.

If you're looking for an alternative to including it in your main installer, simply download it using your main installer if it's needed or place a separate download on your website. I do not recommend this, though, as downloading an extra 72mb these days is only an extra few minutes depending on their download speed.

If you're choosing between having a larger download that takes care of everything and separate downloads, I recommend the larger download. I've done both in the past, and time after time, we've had customers not know to download the "extra" files.